# if condition inThymeleaf.Verify that a date is a DayOfWeek. With th:text it prints MONDAY but if I do the check it doesn't work

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
 <pre>
 <td>
     <span th:each="shift : ${employee.value}"> 
         <span th:if="${#temporals.dayOfWeekName(shift.date)} == 'MONDAY'">
             <button th:text="${shift.start} + '-' + ${shift.end}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shiftDetail">Info</button>
         </span>
     </span>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assignShift">+ 
    </button>
 </td>
 </pre>
```

Comment: You should probably add a bit more explanatory text to your question. E.g. what is the outcome of your code snippet and what is it that you expect instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Thymeleaf `#temporals.dayOfWeekName()` function returns a [formatted string](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time/blob/ca257580ececf8e93ce57fe003e5fe16dde4c1a6/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/extras/java8time/util/TemporalFormattingUtils.java#L116) using the `EEEE` formatter.

The formatter means you will get strings such as `Monday` (not `MONDAY`):

See the [formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) details:

> `E`       day-of-week                 text              Tue; Tuesday; T

When I test with the following, it works as expected (today being Tuesday, for me, at the moment):

```
LocalDate mydate = LocalDate.now();
```

```
<div th:if="${#temporals.dayOfWeekName(mydate)} == 'Tuesday'">
    <div>it worked</div>
</div>
```

I am not sure why you are seeing `MONDAY` when you print your value. But it is worth noting that `MONDAY` is one of the Java enum constants used by [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) - and is also what is returned by its `name()` method.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it works. But I also found this solution th:if=${shift.date.dayOfWeek.toString.equals("MONDAY")}